# GenerationType and MySQL Errors

Tags: mysql, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I have web form where user inserts datas. Then there are stored in the database. But I have got a problem with record in db. I use spring 3, jpa, eclipselink and mysql. In entity @Id is generated. When I use strategy: GenerationType.AUTO, GenerationType.TABLE datas are not stored and error:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Base table or view not found,  message from server: "Table 'sklep.sequence' doesn't exist"
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?bind => [2 parameters bound]

When use GenerationType.IDENTITY, GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  only the first data are storing and then :
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"
Error Code: 1062
What is going on? Is this problem with mysql or something? Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a table SEQUENCE when using TABLE id generation.  If you use EclipseLink to generate your DDL it will be created for you.  You also need to insert a row for each generator name.

For IDENTITY id generation you need to use an IDENTITY type for your id when creating your table.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Sequencing